# Scrapy Tutorial: "No module named" in Sublime editor

Tags: scrapy

**Situation:** I am learning web crawling from scratch. I am doing the [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

**Problem:** No module named scrapy.item

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Thomas/Desktop/test sublime.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scrapy.item import Item, Field
ImportError: No module named scrapy.item
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

Thanks in advance i am a beginner.

Comment: Can you run scrapy from the command line?

Comment: Yes. The problem is on sublime. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to put an empty `init.py`file insider every folder, so python27 can recognize the package.

Answer (score 0):

What path is shown if you type in `which scrapy`? at the command line?

Try adding that path to the Python.sublime-build file (go to Preferences->Browse Packages->Python->Python.sublime-build)

eg:

```
{
    "path": "/usr/bin/",
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```